# Parenthesis in Windows cmd-script variable values not allowed?

Tags: windows, cmd

Why gives the following Windows 7 .cmd command script:

```
set SUN_JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_17

if 3==3 (
 set JAVA_HOME=%SUN_JAVA_HOME%
)
echo ready
```

The following error message instead of printing "ready"

```
\Java\jdk1.6.0_17 was unexpected at this time.
```

The error message disapears, if I remove the "(x86)" in the path name.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478606/batch-file-if-statement-fails-with-was-unexpected-at-this-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the parentheses grouping after the `if 3==3` part.

While parsing the `set JAVA_HOME=%SUN_JAVA_HOME%` command, the interpreter immediately replaces the `%SUN_JAVA_HOME%` variable and that causes an early match of the closing parenthesis in `(386)`.

This can be avoided if you enable [delayed expansion](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/setlocal.mspx?mfr=true) and replace `%SUN_JAVA_HOME%` with `!SUN_JAVA_HOME!`:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set SUN_JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_17

if 3==3 (
    set JAVA_HOME=!SUN_JAVA_HOME!
)
echo ready
```

Answer (score 2):

on the command prompt, enter the following commands

```
C:
CD\
dir /ogen /x
```

This will show you the 8 character name for `Program Files (x86)`

Use that name (probably **"Progra~2"**)

Comment: What exactly does `/ogen` do? `dir /x` is working fine on W8 64-bit.

Comment: `/ogen` is for sorting.  Here is list of switches for the DIR command. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755121.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you have to enclose the set command by double quotes

replace

```
set SUN_JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_17
```

by

```
set SUN_JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_17"
```

because there's a space in the path

Comment: and after the IF use `SET SUN_JAVA_HOME=%SUN_JAVA_HOME:"=%` to remove double quotes, if you need.

Answer (score 0):

I've [written about this a while ago](http://hypftier.de/en/careful-with-those-parentheses) (slightly outdated by now).

As an alternative, if you need grouping the commands, then use a subroutine:

```
if 3==3 call :foo
...
goto :eof
:foo
...
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 0):

[Previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2411067/1193727) is ok. I just want clarify it with simple example. It's about detecting Program Files directory for 32-bit application on x86 and x64 systems. There similar problem with "(x86)".

```
IF DEFINED ProgramFiles(x86) (GOTO x64) ELSE (GOTO x86)
:x64
SET AppDir=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\SomeFolder
GOTO next
:x86
SET AppDir=%ProgramFiles%\SomeFolder

:next
ECHO %AppDir%
```