# Batch file IF statement fails with "was unexpected at this time"

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that does the following:

```
@IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\MyAppFolder" (
  icacls "C:\Program Files\MyAppFolder" /inheritance:r
  icacls "C:\Program Files\MyAppFolder" /GRANT SYSTEM:(CI)(OI)(F)
  icacls "C:\Program Files\MyAppFolder" /GRANT Administrators:(CI)(OI)(F)
)
```

Individually the commands work fine but put together like this in an `IF` statement I get this error and the script stops in its tracks:

```
(OI)(F) was unexpected at this time.
```

If I just have a single command in the `IF` statement then it works fine.

I'm guessing that you're only permitted one statement between the `IF` parenthesis?

This happens on Windows 2008 and Windows 2003 ([with the ICACLS hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943043/)).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The shell seems to think that the `)` in the third line of your command is the closing parenthesis for the one opened in the first line. You need to quote the arguments containing parenthesis:

```
@IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\MyAppFolder" (
  icacls "C:\Program Files\MyAppFolder" /inheritance:r
  icacls "C:\Program Files\MyAppFolder" /GRANT "SYSTEM:(CI)(OI)(F)"
  icacls "C:\Program Files\MyAppFolder" /GRANT "Administrators:(CI)(OI)(F)"
)
```

Comment: Bloody obvious and I should have known better :) Thanks.

Comment: It is 2017 and people like me still need this.. it definitely was not obvious!!

Comment: For usernames with spaces (for example "IIS AppPool\PoolName", use separate inverted commas for sid & perm: /GRANT "SYSTEM":"(CI)(OI)(F)"

Answer (score 0):

The above answer won't work if you need to assign permissions to a user with a  space in their name (EG: "CREATOR OWNER")

A better solution is to use a function with call:

```
@ECHO OFF

IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\MyAppFolder" (
   CALL:Permissions
)

GOTO:eof

:Permissions
   icacls "C:\Program Files\MyAppFolder" /inheritance:r
   icacls "C:\Program Files\MyAppFolder" /GRANT SYSTEM:(CI)(OI)(F)
   icacls "C:\Program Files\MyAppFolder" /GRANT Administrators:(CI)(OI)(F)
   GOTO:eof
```

The GOTO:eof is required at the end of the function.

Detailed information on functions in batch can be found [here](http://www.dostips.com/DtTutoFunctions.php).