# batch file not working

Tags: batch-file, command-line, notepad++

I have a .bat file which check if the file is exist then open file with notepad++

```
set /p File= "Please Enter Your File Name: log."
if exist "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\log.%File%" (
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++
notepad++ C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\log.%File%
exit
)
```

when I just use the command line and execute the below by entering the file name directly it works fine:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++
notepad++ C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\log.2
```

If there is anything wrong in the variable definition or what is the problem??

I am using windows server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell seems to think that the ) in your second command line(X86) is the closing parenthesis for the one opened in the first line. You need to quote the arguments containing parenthesis:

try:

```
set /p File= "Please Enter Your File Name: log."
if exist "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\log.%File%" (
set PATH="%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++"
notepad++ C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\log.%File%
exit
)
```

ref: [Batch file IF statement fails with "was unexpected at this time"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478606/batch-file-if-statement-fails-with-was-unexpected-at-this-time)

Comment: Thanks :-) .. It is working now..Also the shell cannot understand spaces