# Execute powershell command inside IF in bat file - strange behavior

Tags: powershell, batch-file

```
@ECHO OFF     

:: Ask for Credentials
IF NOT EXIST containers/api (
    set /p login="Enter your git username: "
    powershell -Command $pword = read-host "Enter password" -AsSecureString ; $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword) ; [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR) > .tmp.txt & set /p password=<.tmp.txt & del .tmp.txt
)
```

the code above doesn't work with the error message:

*[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR) was unexpected at this time.*

The same code without IF, works just fine

```
@ECHO OFF     

:: Ask for Credentials

set /p login="Enter your git username: "
powershell -Command $pword = read-host "Enter password" -AsSecureString ; $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword) ; [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR) > .tmp.txt & set /p password=<.tmp.txt & del .tmp.txt
```

what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I recommend writing your script in PowerShell instead of trying to run PowerShell as a separate process because you can't ask for a password in a batch file. Much better to rewrite the script in PowerShell instead.

Comment: Bill, if I put powershell line outside of IF - that works.

Comment: This looks like a parsing problem to me. This seems like the `;` in the statement is terminating the powershell command in the `if` case or something like that. If you quote the entire powershell command string does it work?

Comment: I had this problem before: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6478606/419  the unquoted `)` at `SecureStringToBSTR($pword)` prematurely closes the `IF` parenthesis. You'll need to do a bit of string quoting malarky to get this to work. Don't forget you can use single `'` quotes in PowerShell too.

Comment: okay - thank you guys. Once quoted - everything worked. Thanks Etan & Kev!

Comment: That's a lot of trouble to write a workaround just because cmd.exe shell scripting is anemic. Move to PowerShell (a real language) and you don't have to kludge-code stuff like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this is how it worked

```
:: Ask for Credentials
IF NOT EXIST containers/webapp (
    :: Ask for Credentials
    set /p login="Enter your git username: "
    powershell -Command "$pword = read-host 'Enter password' -AsSecureString ; $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword) ; [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)" > .tmp.txt & set /p password=<.tmp.txt & del .tmp.txt 
)
```

then you can use %password%. I used it to automate repo cloning from batch file. Hope this helps