# batch-file escaping parenthesis passed to function

Tags: batch-file, escaping

So I've got the following function to log some information in a script:

```
:Log <Message> <Verbosity>
::%1 - string to log
::%2 - verbosity level for string
    ECHO:%~1
    IF "%verbosity%" GEQ "%~2" (
        ECHO:%DATE:~4,2%/%DATE:~7,2%/%DATE:~10,4% %TIME:~0,2%:%TIME:~3,2%:%TIME:~6,2% - %me% - %~1 >> "%logFile%" 
    )
    ECHO:%DATE:~4,2%/%DATE:~7,2%/%DATE:~10,4% %TIME:~0,2%:%TIME:~3,2%:%TIME:~6,2% - %me% - %~1 >> "%debuglogFile%"
    Exit /B 0
```

It works great until I pass a ) into it.  Which seems to be closing my if statement.

```
    E:\Resources>CALL :Log "Found checkinstall:!value! in E:\Configs\DASABCIP.ini." 3

E:\Resources>ECHO:Found checkinstall:C:\Program Files (x86)\Wonderware\DAServer\DASABCIP\Bin\DASABCIP.exe in E:\Configs\DASABCIP.ini.
Found checkinstall:C:\Program Files (x86)\Wonderware\DAServer\DASABCIP\Bin\DASABCIP.exe in E:\Configs\DASABCIP.ini.

\Wonderware\DAServer\DASABCIP\Bin\DASABCIP.exe was unexpected at this time.

E:\Resources>ECHO:09/25/2017 16:31:15 - WorkerScript - Found checkinstall:C:\Program Files (x86)\Wonderware\DAServer\DASABCIP\Bin\DASABCIP.exe in E:\Configs\DASABCIP.ini.    >> "E:\Log.txt"
```

I've attempted to use delayed extensions as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410501/parenthesis-in-windows-cmd-script-variable-values-not-allowed), but I can't figure out how to do that with the %1 variable. 
 They just end up as an empty string when trying !1!. 
I've also attempted to do a string replacement using message=%1:)=^)%, but wasn't having any luck going that route either. How do I properly escape parenthesis in a variable?

Comment: Did you try: `ECHO "%~1"`

Comment: You can only use delayed expansion with environmental variables.  You can not use it with command line arguments or FOR variables. So you could assign the command line argument to an environmental variable.  Enable Delayed expansion.  Then use your variable with delayed expansion by surrounding the variable name in exclamations.

Comment: The closing parenthesis in `(x86)` is closing the `IF`. You could just fix that by removing the `IF` parentheses as they aren't required anyhow. `IF %verbosity% GEQ %~2 ECHO:%DATE:~4,2%/%DATE:~7,2%/%DATE:~10,4% %TIME:~,2%:%TIME:~3,2%:%TIME:~6,2% - %me% - %~1 >> "%logFile%"`.

Comment: Thanks Squashman & Compo.  the ECHO "%~1" didn't work, but setting a variable then using it with !! worked perfectly!  Compo that worked as well in my scenario thanks for the help.

Comment: I take that back "%~1" does work, but it echos the quotes.  Not ideal, but does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a test bat to show how you you could show a paren or a string with a paren.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set _test_=%2
if %1==0 (
    echo %1
    echo "%2"
    echo %3
    echo !_test_!
)
```

Running this:

```
paren.bat 0 ) test
```

The output is:

```
0
")"
test
)
```

What you may not expect, is that this:

```
paren.bat ) ) test
```

Results in:

```
")"
test
)
```

I think Squashman is onto something with setting a var and using it.  Parens in parameters are somewhat unpredictable.